# Passing values from selected radio button into another input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have a data table, with data coming from the database as stated below:

```
<table id="vehicle" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Reg No</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Colour</th>
            <th>Chasis No</th>
            <th>Mileage</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $vquery = "SELECT * FROM vehicle ORDER BY arrival_date ASC"; // query the person
            $data = perform_query($db, $vquery);
            foreach ($data as $d) {
                $vid = $d['vid'];
                $regNumber = strtoupper($d['reg_no']);
                $model = ucfirst($d['make']);
                $unit_price = $d['purchase_price'];
                $colour = ucfirst($d['colour']);
                $vin_no = strtoupper($d['chasis_no']); ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $regNumber; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $model; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $colour; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $vin_no; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="quantity" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="">
                            <option selected>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                            <option>6</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="unit_price" name="unit_price" value='<?php echo "£" . $unit_price; ?>' style="width: 100%;">
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="selectedVehicle"/></td>
                </tr>
            <?php 
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Upon the user selecting the radio button stated above, the selected vehicle alongside the unit price should automatically copy into an input field in another div with a table below:

```
    <h4 class="panel-title">Payment Information</h4>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="pay-table table-bordered ">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><font color='red'>Sub Total (*):</font></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sub_total" name="sub_total" style="width: 100%;" value="<?php echo $selected_vid  ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font color='red'>Vehicle Reg NO (*):</font></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="extras" name="extras" style="width: 100%;" readonly></td>
                </tr>
```

I have a script that goes through the radioboxes and check which is selected and it alerts the user with the selected vehicle reg no, however I want upon selecting a radio box it should copy the unit price into the Subtotal field.

```
<script>
    rdoBoxes = document.getElementsByName("selectedVehicle"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < rdoBoxes.length; i++) {
        var rdoBox = rdoBoxes[i];
        rdoBox.onclick = function() {
            var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

            alert("You have selected Vehicle Reg No: " + secondColumn.textContent );
        };
    } 
</script>
```

Any tips and help will be highly appreciated. Here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/follypimpz/d5xsq1b5/

Comment: Post the html please or create a fiddle explaining your problem!! This is confusing...

Comment: Never really used jsfiddle before but will create one asap!

Comment: Here is the Jsfiddle @GuruprasadRao http://jsfiddle.net/follypimpz/d5xsq1b5/

Comment: Pure `javascript` or `jquery` will do??

Comment: javascript or jquery?

Comment: I mean jquery sorry @GuruprasadRao

Comment: @vel I mean jquery will edit my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/d5xsq1b5/2/)**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    var parent=$(this).parents('tr'); //get the parent tr
    var vehicleNo=parent.find('td:first').text(); //get the vehicle number which is first td

    var qty=parseInt(parent.find('td select option:selected').text()); //get the quantity
    var unitPrice=parseInt(parent.find('td:nth-child(7) input').val());//get the unitPrice
    var total=qty*unitPrice;//multiply the figures

    $('#sub_total').val(total);//assign it to respective contents
    $('#extras').val(vehicleNo);
});
```

Comment: I wish I can give you a big e-hug right now, Thank you so so so much. I dont know why I feel so dumb

Comment: I hope you got it.. :) Anyways happy coding.. :)

Comment: I am currently going through the solution and if I have any question incase of next time, will it be okay to ask you please

Comment: I pasted the exact code, it works perfectly for the registration no, however for the unit price its saying NaN, any idea please?

Comment: @Raphael Make sure you have same `html` markup. `td:nth-child(7) input` tries to find input which is in `7th` column of table

Comment: I have looked at it over and over, this is how I have it `<td><input type="text" id="unit_price" name="unit_price" value='<?php echo "£" . $unit_price; ?>' style="width: 100%;"></td>` , It is the 7th child definately

Comment: Oh..  You have £ appended to your value.. Just do like this..    `var unitPrice=parseInt(parent.find('td:nth-child(7) input').val().split('£')[1]);`

Comment: It was thr £ sign, took it off and it works perfectly, Thank you once again. Also one last question can you direct me to a link or book that can tutour me on using MVC model for any web based system please

Comment: Thank you and may God bless u, thank u so so so so much. U have made my day

Comment: Anytime body.. Happy coding..  

Comment: @Raphael. You can search for KudVenkat tutorials in youtube which is the source for my MVC knowledge!!

Comment: Will it be okay to exchange email please, I just have few questions regarding building a web based system using MVC

Comment: Will drop you an email now!